# Can I limit the recursion when copying using find (bash)

Tags: macos, bash, recursion, terminal

I have been given a list of folders which need to be found and copied to a new location.

I have basic knowledge of bash and have created a script to find and copy.

The basic command I am using is working, to a certain degree:

```
find ./ -iname "*searchString*" -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec cp -r {} /newPath/ \;
```

The problem I want to resolve is that each found folder contains the files that I want, but also contains subfolders which I do not want.

Is there any way to limit the recursion so that only the files at the root level of the found folder are copied: all subdirectories and files therein should be ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-exec sh -c 'cp "$1"/* /newPath/' -- \;`

Comment: Thanks for the swift response @jordanm but this does not work as hoped: perhaps my description was lacking.  I adjusted the command to `-exec sh -c 'cp ./"$1"/* /newPath/' -- \;` to account for the fact that I was running from the directory above the folders for which I was searching, however it was copying files only and not the  found folders.  To clarify: I need to copy the folder and the files at the first level of recursion, but ignore any contained subdirectories and their contents.

Comment: How do you deal with a case where you have subdirectories to copy?  I.e. if `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/foo/bar` both exist in your source directory list, do they get copied to `/target/foo` and `/target/bar` ?

Comment: Hi @ghoti - at the moment, using my existing command (in the original post) the whole directory structure is copied to the target location, so it will be /target/tmp/foo and /target/tmp/foo/bar. What I am trying to achieve is /target/tmp/files and ignore anything at "bar" level and below. My problem is that the subdirectories do not follow any naming conventions so, for example, any option using excludes would be unwieldy at best.

Comment: Okay, but how do you deal with name conflicts?  If `/source1/foo` and `/source2/foo` both exist, where should those directories be copied to on the target?  I can see doing this in a small shell script.  I can't see doing it in a single `find` command.

Comment: Hi @ghoti - The shell script contains about 200 lines similar to the one in the original question. As I'm only searching to a depth of 1 there are no name conflicts, otherwise there would already be name conflicts in the source directory. The new, target, directory is created specifically for receiving the files, so there are no existing files that could cause conflicts. Hope this clarifies my situation.

Comment: You should perhaps consider using `tar` for copying, it has a lot of options which may do what you want. From memory, something like `tar cf - ...other_tar_creating_options... | tar xf - ...option_for_target_dir...`

Answer (score 0):

If you remove -R, cp doesn't copy directories:

```
cp *searchstring*/* /newpath
```

The command above copies dir1/file1 to /newpath/file1, but these commands copy it to /newpath/dir1/file1:

- `cp --parents *searchstring*/*(.) /newpath`

  - for GNU cp and zsh
  - . is a qualifier for regular files in zsh
  - `cp --parents dir1/file1 dir2` copies file1 to dir2/dir1 in GNU cp
- `t=/newpath;for d in *searchstring*/;do mkdir -p "$t/$d";cp "$d"* "$t/$d";done`
- `find *searchstring*/ -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec rsync -R {} /newpath \;`

  - -R (--relative) is like --parents in GNU cp
- `find . -ipath '*searchstring*/*' -type f -maxdepth 2 -exec ditto {} /newpath/{} \;`

  - ditto is only available on OS X
  - `ditto file dir/file` creates dir if it doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks Lauri, that looks really useful. I must admit to being unaware of the ditto utility and the command you provided seems an elegant solution. However, and I apologise for upping the ante, but the overhead of the new find will increase the runtime by a prohibitive amount. The problem is that I have several scripts which each need to search for 200+ folders, in a folder which contains 20,000+ folders, each containing a minimum of 10 files/folders, which means that the find will need to target approx 200,000 minimum for each line of the script parsed. Definitely get a vote up, though.

Answer (score 0):

So ... you've been given a list of folders.  Perhaps in a text file?  You haven't provided an example, but you've said in comments that there will be no name collisions.

One option would be to use [`rsync`](http://rsync.samba.org/), which is available as an add-on package for most versions of Unix and Linux.  Rsync is basically an advanced copying tool -- you provide it with one or more sources, and a destination, and it makes sure things are synchronized.  It knows how to copy things recursively, but it can't be told to limit its recursion to a particular depth, so the following will copy *each* item specified to your target, but it will do so recursively.

```
xargs -L 1 -J % rsync -vi -a % /path/to/target/ < sourcelist.txt
```

If sourcelist.txt contains a line with `/foo/bar/slurm`, then the `slurm` directory will be copied in its entiriety to `/path/to/target/slurm/`.  But this would include directories contained within `slurm`.

This will work in pretty much any shell, not just bash.  But it will fail if one of the lines in sourcelist.txt contains whitespace, or various special characters.  So it's important to make sure that your sources (on the command line or in sourcelist.txt) are formatted correctly.  Also, rsync has different behaviour if a source directory includes a trailing slash, and you should read the man page and decide which behaviour you want.

You can sanitize your input file fairly easily in sh, or bash.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Avoid commented lines...
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' sourcelist.txt | while read line; do

    # Remove any trailing slash, just in case
    source=${line%%/}

    # make sure source exist before we try to copy it
    if [ -d "$source" ]; then
        rsync -vi -a "$source" /path/to/target/
    fi

done
```

But this still uses rsync's `-a` option, which copies things recursively.

I don't see a way to do this using rsync alone.  Rsync has no `-depth` option, as `find` has.  But I can see doing this in two passes -- once to copy all the directories, and once to copy the files from each directory.

So I'll make up an example, and assume further that folder names do not contain special characters like spaces or newlines.  [(This is important.)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/wiki/ParsingLs)

First, let's do a single-pass copy of all the directories themselves, **not** recursing into them:

```
xargs -L 1 -J % rsync -vi -d % /path/to/target/ < sourcelist.txt
```

The `-d` option creates the directories that were specified in sourcelist.txt, if they exist.

Second, let's walk through the list of sources, copying each one:

```
# Basic sanity checking on input...
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' sourcelist.txt | while read line; do

    if [ -d "$line" ]; then

        # Strip trailing slashes, as before
        source=${line%%/}

        # Grab the directory name from the source path
        target=${source##*/}

        rsync -vi -a "$source/" "/path/to/target/$target/"

    fi 

done
```

Note the trailing slash after `$source` on the rsync line.  This causes rsync to copy *the contents* of the directory, rather than *the directory*.

Does all this make sense?  Does it match your requirements?

Answer (score -1):

You can use find's `ipath` argument:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -ipath './*searchString*/*' -type f -exec cp '{}' '/newPath/' ';'
```

Notice the path starts with `./` to match find's search directory, ends with `/*` in order to exclude files in the top level directory, and `maxdepth` is set to 2 to only recurse one level deep.

**Edit:**

Re-reading your comments, it seems like you want to preserve the directory you're copying from? E.g. when searching for `foo*`:

- ./foo1/* ---> copied to /newPath/foo1/* (not to /newPath/*)
- ./foo2/* ---> copied to /newPath/foo2/* (not to /newPath/*)

Also, the other requirement is to keep `maxdepth` at 1 for speed reasons.

*(As pointed out in the comments, the following solution has security issues for specially crafted names)*

<strike>Combining both, you could use this:

find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*searchString*' -exec sh -c "mkdir -p '/newPath/{}'; cp "{}/*" '/newPath/{}/' 2>/dev/null" ';'</strike>

**Edit 2:**

Why not ditch `find` altogether and use a pure `bash` solution:

```
for d in *searchString*/; do mkdir -p "/newPath/$d"; cp "$d"* "/newPath/$d"; done
```

Note the `/` at the end of the search string, causing only directories to be considered for matching.

Comment: Thanks Sir Athos, but as mentioned on my comment to Lauri's similar answer, the overhead of the new search depth makes the runtime excessively long. As the files are not usually too large, the gain from reducing the number of copies is outweighed by the runtime of the individual finds.

Comment: `find`'s `{}` **is not supposed to be used this way!** This will fail is a file contains a quote. Even worse, do this: `touch 'I will delete your entire directory with my stupid file"; rm -rf *; echo "lol'` and this file suddenly becomes **evil**.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Your example does not execute anything as shown, but you do make a good argument. I was able to attack mkdir with a similarly crafted directory name. Thanks for pointing that out, I'll look for a better solution and edit the answer.

Comment: The solution is to use `sh` with `{}` as argument: `sh -c 'mkdir -p "/newPath/$0"; cp "$0/*" "/newPath/$0/" 2>/dev/null' {}` (note the use of the positional arg `$0` here). If you don't like `$0`, use a dummy argument (traditionally `_`): `sh -c 'mkdir -p "/newPath/$1"; cp "$1/*" "/newPath/$1/" 2>/dev/null' _ {}`.

Comment: Regarding edit2: always use globbings with `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`.